# 2nd and 3rd disks mirrored for backup on Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: server, backup, raid

I wish to set up a small home server providing NAS and Web server functionality to my home network. I'd like to be able to store family pictures and other things I'd want backed up. So I had considered an OS disk alongside a hardware RAID 1 configuration, so three disks in total, the 2nd and 3rd being a mirror of each other.

With hardware RAID, I believe that I'd loose the ability to pull out a surviving disk and plug it into another machine to read/backup the data on it (say my hardware RAID controller goes bust). To get around that I'd considered software RAID.

I'm wondering if there are any other options that I've missed that could provide the mirroring that I want?

Answer (score 0):

There are many [distributed file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems#Distributed_parallel_fault-tolerant_file_systems) [available for Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/36065/which-distributed-file-system-as-a-backend-for-cloud-computing). These are more geared towards server applications like cloud computing, and include the ability to mirror data between computers as well.

Free options include [Lustre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustre_(file_system)) and [GlusterFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlusterFS).

Using software RAID is probably the most common way to do what you want though.